# Google Groups search: Limit search by date (1981 - 1989)?

Tags: google-groups

Google Groups contains an Usenet posts dating [as far back as 1981](http://www.google.com/googlegroups/archive_announce_20.html).

I want to search the Usenet archives for some historical references.

How can I limit my Google Groups search to only be between two dates, say 1981 and 1989?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now part of standard search within Google Groups.

[From Groups: Help: Search and filter](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2371405?hl=en):

> **after:YYYY/MM/DD**
>
> Include only messages created after the YYYY/MM/DD date. For example,
>   **after:2011/11/02**.
>
> **before:YYYY/MM/DD**
>
> Include only messages created before the YYYY/MM/DD date. For example,
>   **before:2011/11/02**.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Google Groups Advanced Search](http://groups.google.com/advanced_search?q=&), specifically the Message Dates date range option.

Comment: the answer to use the advanced search does not work anymore...